# VS Code cannot find virtual environment on the interpreter, but can find it on integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have a fully working virtual environment installed on my Linux machine.
This venv can be regularly used by the terminal in VS code calling `source /mypath/venv/bin/activate`.

The problem is that the Python interpreter in VS code cannot access any of the packages in the virtual environment, despite setting up the path on the interpreter as described in most of the guides.

I decided to manually set up the path in the `settings.json` file inside the `.vscode` folder as follows:

```
{   
   "python.pythonPath": "/mypath/venv/bin/python3.8"
}
```

venv is still not accessible through the interpreter. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Below, I replied to my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question.
Turned out my `pip` installation was pointing to a path (standard `/home/username/.local/bin/pip`) which was different from my `venv` directory (`/my_path/venv/bin/pip`).
You can display the path by executing the command `which pip`.

In my very specific case, there was some mix-up when I first setup my Linux machine, meaning that `venv` only had a small amount of packages installed, while the directory containing the Python libraries and actually being used was the `pip` path. In other words, activating `venv` did not make any difference, since the Python libraries where loaded from the `pip` path.

So, first I had to ensure that `pip` had to point to the my `venv` folder, by modifying the `.bashrc` file  in `/home/username/`, replacing

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8
export PATH=/home/username/.local/bin:$PATH
```

with

```
export PYTHONPATH=/my_path/venv/lib/python3.8/
export PATH=/my_path/venv/bin:$PATH
```

All I had to do after was re-installing each of the required packages in the newer `venv` (generating a `requirements.txt` file from the older `pip` path helped).

Then I selected the `venv` path in the VS Code interpreter and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Wise Python users say that you should not touch `PYTHONPATH` for normal use of Python. The modification of the `PATH` is the activation of the venv. Do you really want to have the venv active all the time? I do not think it will work correctly. It can mess with other venvs created.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need the settings.json file.

You could try to remove the .venv folder and create a new one by

`python -m venv .env`

It seems that vs code have changed something from .venv to .env. I'm not sure why.

After doing `python -m venv .env` open the terminal in vs code and it will active your .env.

You could (if you froze your pip installations) do a `pip install -r requirements.txt` and you are all good to go.

Comment: Hi, is the whole procedure supposed to reinstall all the packages in ```venv``` inside the new virtual environment ```.env```? I do have 100+ GB of data in ```venv```.

Comment: That is something different. The default `.env` is for an environment file! https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file

Answer (score -1):

The default for the "python.envFile" setting is "${workspaceFolder}/.env" change it to "${workspaceFolder}/.venv" and restart vscode.

Comment: That is something different. It is for an environment file! https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file